# flow rate measurement of a fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, torque

I had an experiment related to piping networks in my institute. In the experiment there was a device that was measuring flow rate based on rotations of a fan-like system. This created a doubt in my mind as , a uniform flow rate should not be creating a torque and system was such that the fan was completely covered by water and it was closed and symmetric . Can someone explain the principle and if you know the name of the device i am referring to please mention that as well

Comment: Unless the rotor bearings are truly frictionless, you must apply a torque to keep the rotor at a constant rotation rate.   If frictionless, a constant fluid flow rate should produce, ignoring complications, a constant rotation rate.

Comment: thats my doubt , why does constant flow rate lead to constant rotation rate

Comment: and if so how do you correlate speed of rotation and flow rate

Comment: Why do you doubt that a constant flow rate will produce a constant rotation? What else would it produce? Without any energy being transferred to the rotor there can be no torque and the only way that can be achieved is if the differential velocity between the flow and the surface of the rotor is zero (for an ideal flow meter).

Comment: yeah my doubt was that , why doesn't it just stay there , moreover if it does rotate what dictates the direction and speed of rotation . because in my mind system is uniform so i dont see why rotor rotates in clockwise/anticlockwise direction @CuriousOne

Comment: The rotor in a typical flow meter is not uniform but it has a "twist", which breaks the rotational symmetry and leads to a preferred direction of rotation. I don't know, of course, what you are looking at. The flow meter I am thinking about looks like this:http://www.enggcyclopedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/turbine-flow-meter.png

Comment: @CuriousOne ah i did not know that, i just observed the device from outside and it seemed symmetric to me , but this makes more sense, thanks for the help :)

Comment: It may look symmetric when it rotates fast, that's true.

Comment: It's just a wedge. It travels in a circle, but it's still a wedge.